# How to use the main app and test database as rails engine dummy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rails-engines

I will be adding a series of rails engines that are tightly coupled with the main application. These engines will only be used within this app and the reason is for modularity.

Is there an easy way to use the main app and migrations as the dummy app in the rails engine? Because of tight integration, I find myself rewriting a lot of application code in the dummy app to mimic the main apps functionality.

Please advise with any thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it for testing engine's integration with main app?